# Quote environment with reference at the end right

Tags: environments, line-breaking, quoting

I want to define a quote environment such that after the quote on the right occurs the author with page number. My solution is yet the redefinition of the quote environment

```
\usepackage{amsthm} % pushQED, popQED
\newenvironment{aquote}[1]{%
  \pushQED{#1}%
  \begin{quote}
}{%
  \par\nointerlineskip\noindent\hfill(\popQED)%
  \end{quote}%
}
```

with the following result:

[image]

The drawback is the `parskip` in front of the author, which wastes some space in the first quote, but is right in the second one. If I change my command to:

```
\newenvironment{aquote}[1]{%
  \pushQED{#1}%
  \begin{quote}
}{%
  \noindent\hfill(\popQED)%
  \end{quote}%
}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Now the placement of the author's name in the first quote is perfect, but in the second quote I want a `parskip` in front, like in my first example.

How can I find out, whether the line has enough space to put the author without a `parskip` behind or if there is not enough space to introduce a `parskip` to put the author on the next line?

Comment: Welcome for TeX.SX. I included the images for you. Note if you want to edit your question before you got 10rep points you need to change them to links by removing the `!` in front of them.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There's a nice `\signed` macro that serves this purpose on page 106 of the TeXbook; here's a little variation used to build the `aquote` environment which behaves as expected;

```
\documentclass{book}

\def\signed #1{{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfil\penalty50\hskip2em
  \hbox{}\nobreak\hfil(#1)%
  \parfillskip=0pt \finalhyphendemerits=0 \endgraf}}

\newsavebox\mybox
\newenvironment{aquote}[1]
  {\savebox\mybox{#1}\begin{quote}}
  {\signed{\usebox\mybox}\end{quote}}

\begin{document}

\begin{aquote}{Bourbaki}
This is a case where the name fits in nicely with the quote so the name will appear in the same line.
\end{aquote}

\begin{aquote}{Nicolas Bourbaki}
This is a case where the name won't fit in nicely with the quote, and in this case the name will be moved to the next line.
\end{aquote}

\end{document}
```

Here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Exactly, what I searched for. Also many thanks for the exact reference in the TeXbook.

Comment: Why do you need the the `\savebox`? Is parameter `#1` otherwise unavailable in the closing part of the environment?

Comment: @Christian Lindig: yes,you are right, when defining a new environment, you cannot specify parameters directly in the closing part of the definition; the standard trick is to store them in boxes in the opening part and use the boxes in the closing part.

Comment: `  {\savebox\mybox{(\expandafter\scantokens\expandafter{\detokenize{#1}}\unskip)}\begin{quote}\it}
`  allow to use \bibleref inside when `:` has a 13 catcode. Cf https://framagit.org/maieul/bibleref/issues/13#note_283589

Comment: @GonzaloMedina : would it be possible to modify this `aquote` environment to cancel the white space that comes after it (to use it in a `footnote`, for example)? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, cannot use the `\signed` macro inside `\paragraph`: "\pdfendlink cannot be used in vertical mode"

Comment: Could you please make some explanations to the design of `\signed`?

Answer (score 15):

Also for completeness, please refer to the `attrib` package. You can approximate the effect you want with the following:

```
\begin{quote}
  We call a disposition the arrangement of that which has parts, in respect 
  either of place or of capacity or of kind; for there must be a certain 
  position, as the word ‘disposition’ shows.

  \attrib{{\em Metaphysics} {\greektext D}.19, 1022b1--3}
\end{quote}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, though, because it will always put the attribution on a new line, even if there's room on the existing one.

Comment: @cfr If you don't put the blank line between the paragraph and \attrib, the reference will appear in-line.  See the examples in the documentation for the LaTeX Frankenstein package.

Comment: @phantom-99w Which sort of proves my point.

Answer (score 12):

I just want to add for completeness that the memoir package provides the

```
\sourceatright[⟨length⟩]{⟨text⟩}
```

command, which can be used immediately after a `quote` or `quotation` environment and does what the question asks.

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, the simplest variant I found to achieve this

```
\begin{quote}
  The only way to make the deadline—the only way to go fast—is to keep the code as clean as possible at all times.
  \begin{flushright}
    \tiny{---Robert C. Martin, Clean Code}
  \end{flushright}
\end{quote}
```

[image]

Comment: Like the [answer above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/101967/123129) this doesn't answer the question, because it will always put the author on a new line, even if there's room on the existing one.