# Denoting the end of example/remark

Tags: symbols

What is the etiquette to denote the end of an example or remark? For proofs, it's the QED symbol (white box). I know it's not necessary for everyone, but I would like to use it to break up the text a little. What should I use? A circle or filled box or what?

Comment: Why not the same QED symbol?

Comment: I already use it for proofs so I don't want to use it for anything else.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think this is totally a matter of personal style. If you are using `\qed` already you could use a similar symbol like `\triangle`.

Whatever you do, don't just use `\hfil$\triangle$` because this [does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13756/3083) when your example fills the last line completely. Here is a definition of `\demo` that uses the flexible `\xqed`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcommand\xqed[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand\demo{\xqed{$\triangle$}}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\demo    
\end{document}
```

The `manfnt` font also provides a filled triangle pointing to the right. After declaring `\font\manual=manfnt` you can use `\manual\char'170`.

[image: Two different triangles]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out and get back. Maybe I'll use a different shape than a triangle though.

Comment: The triangle pointing the right looks as though it is a link to somewhere else. What specifically is it supposed to denote?

Comment: @brannerchinese I had no specific meaning in mind, it is just one of the lesser known symbols in the standard fonts. I agree that it suggests a continuation and as such is not appropriate for denoting the end of a section.

Comment: If I have an equation as the last line in my example, unfortunately the character appears a few lines before my last line. Is there a way to change that? I tried putting the `\demo` before the end of equation, but that makes the symbol not align properly.

Comment: @P.A [It works for me](http://imgur.com/b0hEu) so you need to provide an example that does not work.

Comment: Actually my problem is with the second triangle in your example. Ideally I'd like the triangle to appear on the last line (so on the same line as the series) -- like what they say should happen with proofs and the QED symbol (there, if you finish with a displayed equation, you need to use `\qedhere`).
Edit: and sorry, I meant "after my last line" in my above comment.

Comment: Please post a working example as part of your original question or a new question.

Comment: @ChristianLindig: The following question of mine is considered a duplicate of this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317369/well-behaved-qedsymbol-like-for-example-environment?noredirect=1#comment774658_317369 . Still, in my question I give a MWO of the problem that I think the OP mentioned in the comments above. Any feedback is more than welcome.

Answer (score 43):

Try the following indirect method (requires `amsthm`):

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\popQED\endexample}
```

Full example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

% some setup
%
% maybe change here the default symbol
% \renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{...}
%
\NewCommandCopy{\proofqedsymbol}{\qedsymbol}% save the default
\newcommand{\exampleqedsymbol}{$\triangle$}% for end of examples

% ensure that proof has the standard symbol
\AtBeginEnvironment{proof}{\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{\proofqedsymbol}}

% define an environment for examples
\theoremstyle{definition}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\AtBeginEnvironment{example}{%
  \pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}%
}
\AtEndEnvironment{example}{\popQED\endexample}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This has only text.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This has text but also a proof inside it.
\begin{proof}
This is the proof of the above claim.
\end{proof}
And now the example is over.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This has also a display at the end:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \bigl( g(x) \bigr) \\
h(x) &= \bigl( r(x) \bigr).\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

LaTeX has now incorporated `\AtBeginEnvironment` and `\AtEndEnvironment` that used to be only available with `etoolbox`.

#### Original answer

Try the following indirect method (requires `amsthm`):

```
\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}
```

In this way also `\qedhere` works exactly like in `proof`.

Full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This has only text.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This has also a display at the end:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \bigl( g(x) \bigr) \\
h(x) &= \bigl( r(x) \bigr).\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems there's a couple of syntax problems here. (Feel free to remove this comment when fixed.)

Comment: Nice.  With `etoolbox` you can define a command to patch a previously declared theorem type: `\newcommand{\addQEDstyle}[2]{\AtBeginEnvironment{#1{\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{#2}}\AtEndEnvironment{#1}{\popQED}}`.  Call as `\addQEDstyle{example}{$\triangle$}`

Comment: @AndrewSwann That could be an alternative way.

Comment: @AndrewSwann That is an awesome solution, but there is a small typo: `\AtBeginEnvironment{#1` should be `\AtBeginEnvironment{#1}` -> the final brace is missing ;-)

Comment: @wmnorth Yes  thanks - unfortunately I can no longer edit my comment.

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to force example labelling to follow a certain `section`, `subsection` or even `subsubsection`? For example, if I write an example in subsection 3.1.2, I would get Example 3.1.2 (or, for multiple examples in the same section, Example 3.2.1.1, Example 3.2.1.2, and so on). I would be happy if it only follows the leading `section` (so we would get Example 3.1 and Example 3.2). Any ideas?

Comment: @samwolfe That's a completely different topic

Comment: @egreg See here for continued discussion: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650131/labelling-examples-remarks-based-on-section

Comment: @egreg Is it possible to do the same tweak when using examples in multiple languages? (If it should be its own question tell me and I'll ask)

Comment: If I do this (or Andrew Swann's solution) it works as claimed. However, if I put a proof inside the example, it also changes the qedsymbol for the proof ... How can this be avoided?

Comment: @DanFox I modified the code to do what you want.

Answer (score 10):

The very useful `thmtools` package has a key for defining the qed-symbol. For example, I use the following in my documents:

```
\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\declaretheorem[name=Example,qed={\lower-0.3ex\hbox{$◃$}}]{Ex}

...

\begin{Ex}
  The numbers 2, 3 and 5 are all prime.
\end{Ex}
```

(I use `unicode-math` to be able to use the ◃ symbol directly. Just replace it  by whatever symbol you like, e.g. `\triangleleft`.)

Everything is set up correctly so that you can use `\qedhere` like in a standard `amsthm` proof environment.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you’ll like to use the `{leftbar}`-environment?

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{framed}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\begin{leftbar}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{leftbar}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam.
\end{document}
```

If you like it I can show an extended example with a colored bar, no indention of first line an support for floating objects in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use \qed right before \end{example} :

```
\newtheorem{example}[definition]{Example}
.
.
.
\begin{example}
5+6=11
\qed
\end{example}
```

Comment: I believe the downvotes are because the OP specifically stated that `\qed` was not sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: Yes, probably, but it's not necessary to downvote even more (whoever did it ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Wasn't me. +1 to restore balance and welcome a new user.

Comment: @AndrewCashner: I did not suspect you at all ...