# Well-behaved \qedsymbol like for example environment

Tags: amsmath, amsthm

I would like to have a symbol like `\blacksquare` at the end of the environment `\newtheorem{example}{Example}`. However, this symbol should be well-behaved in presence of formulae (i.e. no white space between the formula, and the symbol).

For example, the following line of code does not behave correctly, as can be easily checked.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\newcommand\xqed[1]{%
  \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
  \quad\hbox{#1}}
\newcommand\demo{\xqed{$\diamond$}}

\newtheorem{example}{Example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \bigg( g(x) \bigg) \\
h(x) &= \bigg(r(x) \bigg).
\end{align*}

\demo
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

> How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Might be an idea to switch to `ntheorem` instead of `amsthm`, there every theorem like construction can be given an end marker, which (is used correctly) can place it self "more correctly"

Comment: @daleif: Thanks for the feedback. I will take a serious look at it, even if I would prefer to stick to `amsthm` (most probably kind of an irrational preference, but before getting into something new, I would like to see what happens with in the "known" context).

Comment: To the moderators: This is only partially (at least answer-wise) a duplicate of the question referenced, because by scrolling and checking the comment, the OP did not get an answer to his problem, namely that there is a gap between the last line in the equation and the symbol. See my edit.

Comment: `\qedhere` is the answer

Comment: @egreg: I am trying but it does not work. Moreover, can I personalize `\qedhere` with whatever symbol I want?

Comment: @Kolmin Did you try my answer with `examplex`? If you have a final display in the `example` environment, adding `\qedhere` to the last (or only) line of the display will produce the chosen QED symbol, in that case the triangle.

Comment: @egreg: Now I tried it, and it is really smooth, but  unfortunately still it does not work. The point is that if you write `\qedhere` inside the align, it is literally after the big bracket, while if you put outside at the end, there is still the undesired spacing.

Comment: @Kolmin I added a full example; the triangle is at the right margin as it should.

Comment: @egreg: First of all, thanks a lot for the time you are devoting to this issue, I really appreciate that! Concerning the edit, I saw it, I implemented it, and indeed it works (again thanks!). Now, there is still a small issue that is barely noticeable when we use small braces, but that is evident with big braces, namely that the symbol is in line with the center of the bracket, and not with the bottom as it should be.

Comment: @Kolmin It mostly depends on what you think the position should be. The baseline is the right place, in my opinion. I wouldn't move it.

Comment: @egreg: I see what you mean. It is just that I do not really like how it look like. Anyway, here there is a new question I wrote concerning this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317415/qedhere-in-line-with-the-bottom-of-a-bigg-in-a-formula-that-ends-a-proof-exam . If I remember correctly, somwhere I found an answer where a user (maybe Barbara Beaton) was writing about this issue. However, I am not sure.