# \qedhere in line with the bottom of a \bigg) in a formula that ends a proof/example

Tags: symbols, amsmath, amsthm

This is a a follow-up question to this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32394/92620).

Here there is a minor modification of the MWE provided by the user (where I put `\bigg` instead of `\bigl`/`\bigr`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This has only text.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This has also a display at the end:
\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \bigg( g(x) \bigg) \\
h(x) &= \bigg( r(x) \bigg).\qedhere
\end{align*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

As it can be noticed, the symbol at the end of the example is in line with the dot at the end of the `align` (i.e. it is in line with the center of the bracket). However, I would like to have it in line with the bottom of the bracket.

Notice that the very same issue arises with the standard environment of `proof`.

**Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?**

(Of course, `\bigg)` is just a reference point. The solution should work for any kind of symbol that does not take the standard spacing in a formula.)

Comment: The symbol *should* be aligned with the dot (i.e., the character baseline) and not the bottom of the paren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I recommend this style, but here are two variants of `\qedhere` for use in `align` and `gather` contexts.  They work by adding an extra line to the construction and then backing up vertically an appropriate amount.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\newcommand{\alignqedhere}{\\[\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\dp\strutbox]
&\qedhere}
\newcommand{\gatherqedhere}{\\[\dimexpr-\baselineskip+\dp\strutbox]
\qedhere}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}
This has only text.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
This has also a display at the end:
\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= \bigg( \frac 1{g(x)} \bigg), \\
  h(x) &= \bigg( \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \bigg). \alignqedhere
\end{align*}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
  This ends with an ordinary equation but set as \verb+gather+
  \begin{gather*}
    x = \frac12. \gatherqedhere
  \end{gather*}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
  Here is another example
  \begin{gather*}
    f(x) =
    \begin{cases}
      1&\text{for \( x>0 \),}\\
      0&\text{otherwise.}
    \end{cases}
    \gatherqedhere
  \end{gather*}
\end{example}

\begin{example}
  \begin{gather*}
    \begin{split}
      y &= z\\
      &= \frac 1\pi.
    \end{split}
    \gatherqedhere
  \end{gather*}
\end{example}

\end{document}
```