# Theorem/Definition/Corollary format (font and final symbol)

Tags: environments, theorems

I am writing my thesis and I am using a template that has stuff like:

```
% Theorem definition
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\counterwithin{theorem}{chapter}
```

for a bunch of environments (corollary, definition, example, lemma ,etc.).

I would like to know if I can modify or create new environments such that the text is not in italic, and there is always a symbol (like `\qed`) at the end of all these environments, to mark where it ends.

The italic font is nice, except when you mix math and then all looks italic and wonder if an `a` is an `a` or a math symbol for an object `a`...

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Italic for theorem statements is a very old and established tradition. About end symbols: I'm not sure they are necessary, as the start and ending of a statement are clear (because of the italic). Sometimes examples have an end symbol like proofs.

Comment: But isn't it annoying to have math symbols on the middle of definitions that are in italic? I have the sentence "A literal is a variable or the negation of a variable. That is, $a$ and $\lnot a$ are the literals of variable $a$". I just find it annoying to read. I know I can change the name of the variable, but i'm just 2 pages into my thesis and Im sure its going to happen again. Any elegant suggestion to make this look nice? I would like to keep the italics, but removing them was the only idea that ocurred to me.

Comment: I don't find it annoying. You'll get used to it. Anyhow, this is something you can decide later, provided you structure your document according to the standard guidelines.

Comment: Fair enough. In my papers I always had that and it annoyed me a bit, but the template was fixed. I though maybe choosing this time as it's my thesis. But maybe you are right. As for the symbol at the end, would there be a way of automating it for the Examples/Proof? (I always did it in my papers, but I'm sure in a thesis I'll forget it in at least 20% of them...)

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16453/denoting-the-end-of-example-remark

Comment: Very often, wheras theorems and other to-be-proved statements are in italic, definitions are in upshape.