# How can I automatically append a symbol to an asmthm environment?

Tags: symbols, amsthm

I recently got attached to the idea of finishing definitions, remarks, and observations with something “dual” to `qed` as appended to `\proof` environments – I currently define `\newcommand{\fin}{\hfill\blacklozenge}` and append this manually.

Is there any way to modify my `\newtheorem{obs}[theorem]{Observation}` declaration to automatically append `\fin`?

Comment: This answer provides code that will automatically add a symbol to the end of a theorem-class object: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32394/579 )potential duplicate)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `etoolbox` package to append the `\fin` command to the end of the `obs` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\fin}{\hfill\ensuremath{\blacklozenge}}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observation}
\AtEndEnvironment{obs}{\fin}
\begin{document}
\begin{obs}
Test observation.
\end{obs}
\end{document}
```

Comment: No, if the `\hfill` is chosen as a line break point, the lozenge will be typeset at the beginning of the next line. A `\strut` does nothing to prevent the problem.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing it out, I corrected my answer. I had made a test and it worked, so I thought it would solve the problem. I guess I have just been lucky with the placement of the line break.