# Labelling examples/remarks based on Sections

Tags: sectioning, symbols, labels, examples

I want to automatically label examples (as well as remarks, definitions, theorems, etc) based on section number. For example, if I have defined a `\section`, `\subsection` or even a `\subsubsection` environment, I want to be able to automatically label my examples within that section such that I get, taking Section 3.2 for instance, something like

**Example 3.2.1** (First example in Section 3.2). This is an example.

**Examples 3.2.2** (Second example in Section 3.2). This is another example.

A new example in Section 3.3 would be labelled as

**Example 3.3.1** (First example in Section 3.3). Yet another example.

However, I want to also keep denoting the end of the example by some specific character, such as the triangle, as automatically defined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32394/188902). Any ideas on how to extend this (or other) answer to account for this labelling property and keep the example ending automatic symbol?

Comment: You can  use, say,  `\counterwithin{example}{section} in you preamble.

Comment: With amsmath, one typically does `\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}[subsection]` to get this behavior, but do you have some sections without subsections or some subsections without subsubsections? If so should some of just be "Example 3.1" (if in a section w/o subsections) whereas others are Example "3.2.2" (if in a subsection w/o subsubsection) or "Example 3.1.2.1" (if in a subsubsection), or will they all be the same nesting level? That would make it a little trickier.

Answer (score 2):

Make `examplex` subordinate to `subsubsection` and define suitably `\theexamplex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{examplex}{Example}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand{\theexamplex}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0 \thesubsubsection \else
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 \thesubsection \else
  \thesection \fi\fi .\arabic{examplex}%
}
\newenvironment{example}
  {\pushQED{\qed}\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\triangle$}\examplex}
  {\popQED\endexamplex}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\subsection{Test}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\subsubsection{Test}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\section{Another}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\subsection{Another}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\subsubsection{Another}

\begin{example}
Text
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please, don't inflict this to your readers.

Comment: Brilliant answer! How would you suggest defining the labels?

Comment: Is it possible to simply make it change with `chapter`? Or `section`?

Comment: @samwolfe Use either `[chapter]` or `[section]` instead of `[subsubsection]` and don't redefine `\theexamplex`