# Place the citation flush right csQuotes

Tags: quoting, csquotes

I very much like the way the citations are done in this answer here
[Quote environment with reference at the end right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13756/quote-environment-with-reference-at-the-end-right)
Is there any way to get the same effect using csQuotes? Beneath is a somewhat minimal example =)

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{Feynman,
        author = "Richard P. Feynman",
        title = "Surely You're Joking, Mr.Feynman!",
        publisher = "WW.Norton Company, Inc",
        year = "1985"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sort,numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[lipsum]

\begin{document}

\textquote[Feynman \citep[s39-41]{Feynman}]{\lipsum[1]}{}{}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}    

\end{document}
```

Here is what I get

[image: What I get]

And here is what I want =)

[image: What I want]

I did try a few dirty fixes, such as defining new environments and what not. But most likely the people here are far more experienced in using these packages =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two problems here. Left to its own devices, `lipsum` puts a `\par` at the end of the text -- that is why your concluding quote mark (and `\cite`) came out on the next line. You need to use `\lipsum*[1]` so that the `\par` token is not inserted.

The other problem is getting the flushright effect: You need to redefine `\mktextquote`:

```
\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#3\hfill\hbox{#6}#5}
```

So the whole file looks like this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@book{Feynman,
        author = "Richard P. Feynman",
        title = "Surely You're Joking, Mr.Feynman!",
        publisher = "WW.Norton Company, Inc",
        year = "1985"
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[sort,numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\signat}[1]{%
    {%
        \unskip
        \nobreak
        \hfil
        \penalty50%
        \hskip2em%
        \hbox{}%
        \nobreak
        \hfil
        #1%
        \parfillskip=0pt%
        \finalhyphendemerits=0% 
        \endgraf
     }%
}


\renewcommand{\mktextquote}[6]{#1#2#4#3\signat{#6}#5}

\begin{document}

\textquote[{\cite[s39-41]{Feynman}}]{\lipsum*[1]}{}{}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}    

\end{document}
```

I have modified my answer to include a version of Knuth's `\signed` that takes only one argument. You can try that. However, as I run your file (on TeXLive2013), I am not getting a name ("Feynman") but a number ("1") so I cannot replicate your problem with a long name which was what, by the way?

For the sake of completeness, `\mkblockquote` can be redefined analogously:

```
\renewcommand{\mkblockquote}[5]{#1#2#3\signat{#4}#5}
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use \hfill\hbox{} instead of the \signed. I tried your code, and ran into a few problems with long names. The problem imgur.com/MYEOmkl and the code pastebin.com/WfUz4Z3N. I found that removing the parenthesis and using the `\signed` command from the linked question fixes this. I would recommend using this instead, (or find your own way to fix the brokenlines) Otherwise a really useful answer, thanks!