# (1), (2)... at the end of a line

Tags: hyperref, tags, tag

**Thank you very much, K. Paul and Ignasi ❤ You have provided me solutions that suit my document perfectly! However -- well -- which answer should I mark to be 'accepted' when both are correct?**

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

**What I have**

I have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
We have $1+1=2$. (1)

Besides, we already have $3-1=2$. (2)

Since (1) and (2) we get $1+1=3-1$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

**What I want**

I want to have the result like this

[image]

where the black (1) and (2) are at the end of the line (like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273446/pushing-text-to-the-end-of-the-line) question), but I can label them and then cite them in the next lines by the clickable red (1) and (2).

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

A part of my document (in Vietnamese):

[image]

I want to change the position of the (3) (red arrow), but other equations (especially display equation as the blue arrow pointing) should not be affected.

Comment: Can you point to a source where such typesetting is used? Commonly, equations to be referred to are displayed by themselves on a line.

Comment: @egreg I use `1+1=2` for a short and simple MWE. However, I use it in geometry, like `Since AB=BC, we get that ΔABC is isosceles (1)`. The way of writing `ΔABC is isosceles` in the center of a new line is not quite good to me.

Answer (score 2):

A command which increases `equation` counter and that can be placed where you want, could work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\myeq}[1]{\hfill{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{#1}}}

\begin{document}

We have $1+1=2$. \myeq{1}

Besides, we already have $3-1=2$. \myeq{2}

This is a nonnumbered equation
\[
x+y=z+d
\]

Another equation with number
\begin{equation}
x+y=z+d
\end{equation}

Another inline expression $a+b=2$. \myeq{z}

Since \ref{1} and \ref{2} we get $1+1=3-1$. And with \ref{z} \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It looks nice, but in my document there are still many equations which I put in a unique line (display equation). I don't want to ruin them :D See more in [my image](https://i.imgur.com/hwIjJ5H.png).

Comment: @joule_voo    I've provided another solution, is it better?

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I want to have!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the `amsmath` and `hyperref` packages for this one:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\textrm{We have }1+1=2&&\label{eq:1}
\end{flalign}
\begin{flalign}
\textrm{Besides, we already have }3-1=2&&\label{eq:2}
\end{flalign}
Since \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:2} we get $1+1=3-1$
\end{document}
```

The `flalign` environment is provided by the `amsmath` package. Make sure to add the symbol `&&` after each equation to make them flush left. Labeling is done by the `\label{eq:n}` command in every `flalign` environment. Referencing in-line is done by the `\eqref{eq:n}` command. (I used `n` in describing the equation number.)
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The solution above was a partial solution that only works within displayed equations. Thw following presents a solution *specifically for in-line equations*:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\plusone}{\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
\textrm{We have }1+1=2&&\label{eq:1}
\end{flalign}
\noindent Writing an in-line math equation \(E=mc^2\) and filling up some space so that
this sentence covers more than one line... \hfill \(\plusone \label{eq:2}\)
\begin{flalign}
\textrm{Besides, we already have }3-1=2&&\label{eq:3}
\end{flalign}
Since \eqref{eq:1} and \eqref{eq:3} we get $1+1=3-1$. \eqref{eq:2} is irrelevant but hey,
it was a good example.
\end{document}
```

`\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)` increments equation count, so every time you need to reference in-line equations, add this mark at the end of the paragraph. I've made a macro so no one needs to write that long code all the time. Always remember to `label` and `eqref` after every increment. `\hfill` was used so that the (`n`) is always flushed right after every paragraph. Use it after your last sentence to flush only the numbering part right. Compiling prints this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works perfectly for a line but for a paragraph (like in the last image I put in the question) I still don't really get what I want :( (see [this](https://i.imgur.com/78DqD3L.png) image)

Comment: I've made a workaround for said problem. Seems as though the display mode was making margin problems, so I've made a workaround for said problem by implementing a similar solution for in-line math equations. I'm editing the answer now...

Comment: Thank you very much! That is exactly what I want to have!!!

Comment: Added a picture, just for good measure.