# Quote with author reference at the end

Tags: macros

I have redefined quote environment to allow me to put author at the end of quotation, but I have a mistake somewhere in my code, could someone check it:

```
%Add source argument to quote
\let\oldquote\quote
\newsavebox\first
\newsavebox\second
\renewenvironment{quote}[2][0]
  {\savebox\second{#1}
   \savebox\first{#2}
  \begin{oldquote}}
  {\smallskip\par\hfill(\usebox\first ~---~\usebox\second)\bigskip\break
  \end{oldquote}}
```

If I try to use more than 6 of those I get "Too deeply nested" error, so I assume I don't end the environment correctly, but I can't find the error.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When LaTeX finds `\end{oldquote}` it just ends the group, but not the (original) `quote` environment, because `\endoldquote` is not defined.

Add also

```
\let\endoldquote\endquote
```

Remove the final `\break`, whose only effect is to issue an “Underfull `\hbox` (badness 10000)” warning.

---

It's not clear why the renewed `quote` environment has an optional argument: setting the default to `0` would make

```
\begin{quote}{Somebody}
<text>
\end{quote}
```

to print “(Somebody — 0)” which doesn't seem wanted.

See also [Quote environment with reference at the end right](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13756/quote-environment-with-reference-at-the-end-right) for a very similar problem.

---

A possible refinement:

```
\documentclass{article}

\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote
\renewenvironment{quote}[2][]
  {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
     \def\quoteauthor{#2}%
   \else
     \def\quoteauthor{#2~---~#1}%
   \fi
   \oldquote}
  {\par\nobreak\smallskip\hfill(\quoteauthor)%
   \endoldquote\addvspace{\bigskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}{Somebody}
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}[Somewhere]{Somebody}
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Note the inversion between `\par` and `\smallskip`, with the addition of `\nobreak` to avoid a page break between the quote and the attribution. Storing the arguments in boxes is not needed; it's easier to store them in a macro that will contain different things when the optional argument is missing. Also the `\bigskip` is better placed after closing the (original) `quote`.

[image]

A simpler approach with `xparse`, where it's possible to use the arguments also in the “end part”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\let\oldquote\quote
\let\endoldquote\endquote

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{quote}{om}
  {\oldquote}
  {\par\nobreak\smallskip
   \hfill(#2\IfValueT{#1}{~---~#1})\endoldquote 
   \addvspace{\bigskipamount}}

\begin{document}

\begin{quote}{Somebody}
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
\end{quote}

\begin{quote}[Somewhere]{Somebody}
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
This is a quote This is a quote This is a quote
\end{quote}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `~---~` means? It's basically ungoogleable, so I'm having a hard time finding documentation.

Comment: @Merchako `~` is an “unbreakable space”, `---` an em-dash.